# `endIndex` and `count` of a String are different

Tags: swift, swift2

How is it possible to `endIndex` and `count` of a `String` be different in swift2? its the code sample that I've used.it's not happen when all characters are english only.

```
    print("count:",self.Label.text!.characters.count)
    print("endIndex:",self.Label.text!.characters.endIndex)
    print("String:",self.Label.text!)
```

output :

```
count: 32
endIndex: 34
String: • (دستور زبان) مفعول‌به، مفعول‌عنه
```

Comment: what about swift 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw value of `String.CharacterView.Index` is irrelevant and should not be used.  Its raw value only has meaning from within String and CharacterView.

In your case, some Unicode characters are merely combining characters that modify adjacent characters to form a single grapheme.  For example, U+0300, Combining Grave Accent:

```
    let str = "i\u{0300}o\u{0300}e\u{0300}"

    print("String:",str)
    print("count:",str.characters.count)
    print("endIndex:",str.characters.endIndex)

    var i = str.characters.startIndex
    while i < str.characters.endIndex
    {
        print("\(i):\(str.characters[i])")
        i = i.successor()
    }
```

results in

```
String: ìòè
count: 3
endIndex: 6
0:ì
2:ò
4:è
```

Comment: do you know how can I get order of character? I mean getting 2 for index of 4 in your example è

Comment: Use `distanceTo()` to get the number of characters between two indexes.  `startIndex.distanceTo(i)` returns to "2" for index "4".  Use `advanceBy()` to increment an index by a number of characters.

Comment: I have an integer form layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(...) I don't know how to convert it to Sting.Index type

Comment: startIndex.advancyBy(number)

Comment: this Int is 4 for è not the 2